# What is the most efficient way to dig a hole in a slope?

Tags: installation

I need to dig a rectangular box hole for a rainwater cistern. The dimensions are 4m x 3m x 2m (13ft x 10ft x 6ft). There is a slope of about 10 degrees, and the dirt will be used at a point of lower elevation. The soil is a mix of clay and residues of bricks.

Given the amount of soil that needs to be removed, I'm looking for the easiest way to excavate this much material. I have a wheelbarrow, shovels, and pickaxe to use for the task. Is there any way I can use the slope itself to make the task easier?

Comment: Be VERY CAREFUL digging a deep trench and then working in it, unless you are digging a grave and don't care if you are the eventual occupant of said grave. The walls can collapse, leaving you less than happy.

Comment: Wow - 780 cubic feet of soil, or about 32 tons.

Comment: Not digging by hand would avoid a lot of work...

Comment: Get some dynamite... ;)

Answer (score 11):

Rent a small excavator, perhaps including a person to operate it. A machine can do in hours what you would spend days (or weeks!) doing with two hands and one shovel.

[image]

Comment: +1 In my opinion it is silly to do a job like this without heavy machinery. Digging a 6ft hole by hand is backbreaking work.

Answer (score 6):

You should try to rent a dirt conveyor:

[image]

Also, dig across, not down - do it in horizontal layers, a foot at a time, not vertical stripes.  That will be much less dangerous.